# Swift - UIActionSheet events does not work

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiactionsheet

I'm trying to add actions/events to my action sheet, but when the buttons are pressed, nothing happens.
My code looks like this:

```
@IBAction func sendTapped() {

    var sheet: UIActionSheet = UIActionSheet()
    let title: String = "Choose item to send:"
    sheet.title  = title
    sheet.addButtonWithTitle("Cancel")
    sheet.addButtonWithTitle("Text")
    sheet.addButtonWithTitle("Image")
    sheet.cancelButtonIndex = 0
    sheet.delegate = self
    sheet.tag = 1
    sheet.showInView(self.view)

    func actionSheet(sheet: UIActionSheet!, clickedButtonAtIndex buttonIndex: Int) {
        switch (sheet.tag){

        case 1:
            println("1 pressed")

        case 2:
            println("2 pressed")
        default:
            println("Nothing pressed")
        }
    }

}
```

Honestly I do not know why this wouldn't work. Please help me solve this problem.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this code copied and pasted verbatim? Because if so you're implementing your delegate function as a standalone function inside the scope of sendTapped(), when it should be a member function of whatever object this is. Just try moving it outside one level of `{}`. Also I would suggest using `UIAlertController` as `UIActionSheet` and `UIAlertView` are soft deprecated as of iOS 8.

Comment: If that solves your problem then you'll also what to do what soulshined says below, `-[UIView tag]` is not what you want to switch on here, `buttonIndex` is.

Comment: @axiixc This is Swift, so "UIView.tag is not what you want to switch on here." Square brackets syntax does not make sense to Swift coders. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frank. You have the right idea. Your calling the clicked button index against the sheet tag. Instead call it against the button itself :

```
func actionSheet(actionSheet: UIActionSheet, clickedButtonAtIndex buttonIndex: Int) {
switch buttonIndex {
    case 0: // your cancel button 
Etc
}
}
```

Additionally, if your coding for iOS8 it has been deprecated for UIAlertController which contains handlers. A lot easier. Just FYI. But if you are making it backwards compatible it doesn't work with iOS7.

Additionally make sure your setting your delegate